# CONVERT_TZ issue with Etc/GMT?

Tags: java, mysql

`select CONVERT_TZ(now(), @@session.time_zone, 'Etc/GMT+5:30')` giving null value as result. Does anyone know why this is? Seems like: 30 is not allowing

Answer (score 0):

To convert to IST, try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(now(), @@session.time_zone, '-05:30')
```

The timezones available are read from `/usr/share/zoneinfo` on the server you are hosting, and `Etc/GMT+5:30` doesn't exist

Here's a list of Linux timezones:

https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/tzdata/filelist

If you look at the following link, you will notice there is no timezone that exists as `Etc/GMT+5:30`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones